# How to prove the Span of a set $S$ is equal to $\Bbb{R}^2$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

absolutely baffled. need to prove $\operatorname{Span}\{(2,1), (-1,3), (0,1)\} = \Bbb{R}^2$,

I started by showing that $(2,1)$ can be written as $-2(-1, 3) + 7(0,1)$ but thats it so far

Comment: Since each vector in the spanning set is in $\mathbb R^2$, we just need to prove the reverse inclusion: $\mathbb R^2\subseteq\operatorname{Span}((2,1),(-1,3),(0,1))$. To do this, can you write any $(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2$ as a linear combination of the vectors in this spanning set? To do this in general, see egreg's answer (in particular the matrix).

Answer (score 3):

Since $(0,1)$ belongs to the set, you just need to show that $(1,0)$ belongs to the span, which is clear enough:
$$
(1,0)=\frac{1}{2}\bigl((2,1)-(0,1)\bigr)
$$
More systematically, consider the matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 2 & -1 & 0 \\ 1 & 3 & 1 \end{bmatrix}
$$
and perform Gaussian elimination to show that the matrix has rank $2$.

Comment: we havent covered gaussian elimination yet so i cant use it in my proof